# Too many DDL occur when using @DataJpaTest in H2DB

Tags: jpa, junit5

I changed `JUnit4` to `JUnit5`.

Also previously, testing with `MSSQL`, but we changed it to `H2DB`.

The problem occurred at this time.

**My legacy project has about 400 tables.**

If you conduct a persistence test using `@DataJpaTest`, **occurred  more than 400 CREATE DDLs.**

I looked for a solution to solve this problem, but the best-looking solution I found was to pre-write about 400 Create DDLs in `schema.sql`.

What I want.

I want to create a `MEMBER table` only when there is a code like the following, and test only the `MEMBER table`.

```java
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long>{
}
```

Do you have any useful features or solutions for `JUnit5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **application-test.yml** for testing config and set **ddl-auto** to **none**.

application-test.yml

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Use `@ActiveProfiles("test")` to start **application-test.yml** and `@Sql("Member.sql")` for Testing script.

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DataJpaTest
public class MemberRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql("Member.sql")
    public void testSomething() {
        Member member = memberRepository.findById(1L).orElse(null);
        assertThat(member).isNotNull();
        assertThat(member.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
    }
}
```

Create the **Member.sql** to `scr/test/resource/com.yourpackage`

```
create table if not exists member (id bigint not null, primary key (id));
insert into member (id) values (1);
```

In this case, DDLs will not create the table and you can custom your sql to run something on the MemberRepository.

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/changemyminds/stackoverflow/tree/master/68341902).